# Sympy: Step-by-step calculation of an ODE system using indexed objects

Tags: python, controls, simulation, sympy

I currently want to implement a Hammerstein model in sympy. I have now created a small example for a simple system:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

####HAMMERSTEIN MODEL####
#time
t = symbols("t")

#inputs
u = symbols('u')

#states 
y = symbols('y',cls = Function, Function = True)

#init states
y_init =symbols('y_init')

#parameters
gain = 2 #symbols('gain')
time_constant = 20000#symbols('time_constant')


#EQUATIONS

#NONLINEAR STATIC PART 
u_nonlinear = u**2 # nonlinear input


#DYNAMIC PART
# first order system with inputs
rhe = (gain * u_nonlinear - y(t)) * 1/time_constant
ode = Eq(diff(y(t),t),rhe)

#solve equation
sol_step = dsolve(ode, ics = {y(0): y_init})
sol_step = sol_step.rhs

#lambdify (sympy)
system_step =lambdify((t,u, y_init),sol_step, 'sympy')


#####SIMULATE STEPWISE######
nr_steps = 10
dt=1
u_data =IndexedBase('u_data')
y_init_data =symbols('y_init_data')

#solution vector 
sol =[]

for i in range(nr_steps):

    #first sim. step
    if i == 0:
        sol.append(system_step(dt,u_data[i],y_init_data))

    #uses the states of prev. solution as inits
    else:
        sol.append(system_step(dt,u_data[i],sol[i-1]))

#convert
system=lambdify((u_data,y_init_data),sol, 'numpy')   


#EXAMPLE
t_obs = np.linspace(0,10,10)
u_obs = np.ones(10)* 40
x_obs_init =20

#RESULT
print(system(u_obs,x_obs_init))
```

As you can see from the example, I solve the problem step by step. I always call the Sympy function object "system_step".
The performance is not particularly good with larger systems.

However, I would also like to use the simulation in a scipy optimizer, which leads to it being called several times, which extremely increases the solution time

My problem:

1.)
Can this step-by-step calculation also be implemented using sympy (e.g. indexed objects)? Can the repeated calculation in the loop be avoided?

2.) If so, how can this be done if the length of the input variables (u) should remain flexible and not be specified by a fixed index (m) using hardcode (see nr_steps).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that sympy has done its job here after the call to dsolve and lambdify. Everything else is just numerics that will run much faster if you do it by calling `system_step` with numeric values

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the info. If I calculate the ODE system with constant input values, I do not need to calculate it step by step. Then the solution process is very quick. Therefore, my idea was to set up the system using vectors or indexed objects, which can prevent the step-by-step calculation.

My goal:

- set up the system with variable input variables
- solve the system symbolically, even if it takes a very long time
- Lambdify and storage in a binary file
- use the solved system for different operations